# Cant access uploaded files (flv&images) in drupal

Tags: drupal, file-upload, access-denied

I have a custom upload field with a content type which allows to upload flv files. And I have jw player in my theme which plays it for me. Everything works fine in my localhost.
But after uploading it show `Access Denied or File not found Error.`

I checked the permission of files folder, it seems to be ok. Directly typing the link to the file also returns page not found.

What is the problem? What can be done? 
I tried with absolute url using `print $base_url` and also tried with `print $base_path` both of which work really well in localhost.

**Update:** even the thumbnail of image_cache or any uploaded images are not accessible. This is kind of weird. I cant figure this out.

.htacess is same in localhost and server. But why only in server I cant access? I checked
the log and its show pagenotfound error for all attempts.

My .htaccess file :

```
> #
> # Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
> #
> # Protect files and directories from prying eyes. <FilesMatch
> "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|svn-base)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|all-wcprops|entries|format)$">
> Order allow,deny </FilesMatch>
> # Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory. Options
> -Indexes
> 
> 
> 
> # Make Drupal handle any 404 errors. ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
> 
> # Force simple error message for requests for non-existent favicon.ico.
> <Files favicon.ico>   # There is no
> end quote below, for compatibility
> with Apache 1.3.   ErrorDocument 404
> "The requested file favicon.ico was
> not found. </Files>
> 
> # Set the default handler. DirectoryIndex index.php
> 
> # Override PHP settings. More in sites/default/settings.php
> # but the following cannot be changed at runtime.
> 
> # PHP 4, Apache 1. <IfModule mod_php4.c>   php_value
> magic_quotes_gpc                0  
> php_value register_globals            
> 0   php_value session.auto_start      
> 0   php_value mbstring.http_input     
> pass   php_value mbstring.http_output 
> pass   php_value
> mbstring.encoding_translation   0
> </IfModule>
> 
> # PHP 4, Apache 2. <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>   php_value
> magic_quotes_gpc                0  
> php_value register_globals            
> 0   php_value session.auto_start      
> 0   php_value mbstring.http_input     
> pass   php_value mbstring.http_output 
> pass   php_value
> mbstring.encoding_translation   0
> </IfModule>
> 
> # PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2. <IfModule mod_php5.c>   php_value
> magic_quotes_gpc                0  
> php_value register_globals            
> 0   php_value session.auto_start      
> 0   php_value mbstring.http_input     
> pass   php_value mbstring.http_output 
> pass   php_value
> mbstring.encoding_translation   0
> </IfModule>
> 
> # Requires mod_expires to be enabled. <IfModule mod_expires.c>   # Enable
> expirations.   ExpiresActive On
> 
>   # Cache all files for 2 weeks after
> access (A).   ExpiresDefault A1209600
> 
>   <FilesMatch \.php$>
>     # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send
> cache
>     # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite
> the
>     # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior.
> This may
>     # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may
> cause
>     # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
>     ExpiresActive Off   </FilesMatch> </IfModule>
> 
> # Various rewrite rules. <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>   RewriteEngine on
> 
>   # If your site can be accessed both
> with and without the 'www.' prefix,
> you   # can use one of the following
> settings to redirect users to your
> preferred   # URL, either WITH or
> WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY
> one option:   #   # To redirect all
> users to access the site WITH the
> 'www.' prefix,   #
> (http://example.com/... will be
> redirected to
> http://www.example.com/...)   # adapt
> and uncomment the following:   #
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
> ^example\.com$ [NC]   # RewriteRule
> ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1
> [L,R=301]   #   # To redirect all
> users to access the site WITHOUT the
> 'www.' prefix,   #
> (http://www.example.com/... will be
> redirected to http://example.com/...) 
> # uncomment and adapt the following:   # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]   #
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$
> http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
> 
>   # Modify the RewriteBase if you are
> using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
> # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.   #
> For example if your site is at
> http://example.com/drupal uncomment
> and   # modify the following line:   #
> RewriteBase /drupal   #   # If your
> site is running in a
> VirtualDocumentRoot at
> http://example.com/,   # uncomment the
> following line:   # RewriteBase /
> 
>   # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to
> the form 'index.php?q=x'.  
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}
> !=/favicon.ico   RewriteRule ^(.*)$
> index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA] </IfModule>
> 
> # $Id: .htaccess,v 1.90.2.5 2010/02/02 07:25:22 dries Exp $
```

.htacess in the file directory:

```
> SetHandler
> Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
> Options None Options -FollowSymLinks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure you uploaded the .htaccess file to Drupal's root directory.

Is your site running at the root of the domain or in a subdirectory? If it's in a subdirectory, you may need to set RewriteBase in the .htaccess file.

Check the **Admin > Reports > Status reports** page to see if there are any error messages.

Check the **Admin > Reports > Recent log entries** for any additional errors.

Comment: Your questions states that you get an error "Access Denied" or "File not found." You should get one or the other, not both. Can you clarify? Is the error page you receive a Drupal-themed page or a standard Apache error page?

Comment: drupal page... the thing is the file are there in the files folder. But drupal is not able to get any files from that folder. Even if i link an image directly its not loading.

Comment: Which error are you getting specifically, "Access Denied" or "File not found"?

Comment: Do you have the filetype specified under "Default permitted file extensions" on admin/settings/uploads?

Answer (score 0):

There should be another htaccess in your files directory. Any permissions set in this file will override those set at the root level. As an alternative you could set Drupal to handle your files (the private filesystem option). Be aware that setting files to private will have a performance impact.

Comment: I have added that .htacess to the bottom of my question

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above Setting the **/sites/default** directory permission to 555 should fixed it either 404 or 403.

I missed that too